# Formula produces numbers that can't be calculated

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula, that extracts a number from a cell (like bla bla Pris: xxx.00):

MID(A3:A2000,FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)+6,FIND(".00",A3:A2000)-FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)-6)

The result is correctly xxx

But xxx can't be calculated on in other cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VALUE()` function to convert a string into a number.

So it will look like

```
=VALUE( MID(A3:A2000,FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)+6,FIND(".00",A3:A2000)-FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)-6) )
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(MID(A3:A2000, FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)+6, 
                     FIND(".00",   A3:A2000)- 
                     FIND("Pris: ",A3:A2000)-6)*1)
```

or just:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, "Pris: (\d+)\.")*1)
```